problems with firewire OHCI when trying to rip tapes from camcorder using dvgrab
i recently switched to full-timing Linux, and i'm having problems transferring miniDV tapes under Fedora 40.
so, i've got a camcorder which is capable of offloading the content of tapes via a firewire (ieee1394) cable to a PC, via a firewire PCI capture card.
first of all i want to be very clear. these tapes, and the cables, and the camcorder, and the PCI card are in pristine condition. i transferred several tapes while i was still living under Windows using WinDV, and had no problems whatsoever, with all the same hardware (same workstation, same camcorder, same cables even). the video on the camcorder plays back flawlessly, with audio and not a single glitch or drop-out. the hardware is not the problem.
however, when trying to capture tape contents with dvgrab, i get the following output:
sudo dvgrab -buffers 512 -f dv2 -noavc -nostop -showstatus test

Found AV/C device with GUID 0x0000850000a1c0c4
Waiting for DV...

"": damaged frame near: timecode 45:85:85.45 date 2024.08.03 08:54:22
This means that there were missing or invalid FireWire packets.
Capture Started

"": damaged frame near: timecode 45:85:85.45 date 2024.08.03 08:54:22
This means that there were missing or invalid FireWire packets.

"": damaged frame near: timecode 45:85:85.45 date 2024.08.03 08:54:22
This means that there were missing or invalid FireWire packets.

followed by an endless stream of identical errors until i eventually give up and CTRL+C it.
the resulting output looks like this, for reference:

ignoring my shoddy camerawork, dvgrab produces a mess of visual artefacts as well as constantly clicking, staticy audio.
having looked for a solution to this problem, the only relevant posts seem to talk about a problem with Ubuntu's (not Fedora, but it may have been common between the two) new firewire/1394 driver causing some problems, (though most of those posts seem to talk about the device not being detected, and my current setup is at least capable of seeing and talking to the camcorder) but all of these posts are from a decade ago and most seem to have been resolved in the form of 'the next OS update has fixed it'.
looking more into what's happening, i find i have the following kmodules installed:
sudo lsmod | grep firewire

firewire_ohci          65536  0
firewire_core         110592  1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t              12288  1 firewire_core

but more interesting is the output of dmesg. before trying to run dvgrab, the output is limited to the following:
[    3.602743] firewire_ohci 0000:08:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.656409] firewire_ohci 0000:08:00.0: added OHCI v1.10 device as card 0, 4 IR + 8 IT contexts, quirks 0x2
[    4.158481] firewire_core 0000:08:00.0: created device fw0: GUID 00000000000002ea, S400

but after running dvgrab, we end up with an avalanche of IO_PAGE_FAULT errors:
[    3.602743] firewire_ohci 0000:08:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.656409] firewire_ohci 0000:08:00.0: added OHCI v1.10 device as card 0, 4 IR + 8 IT contexts, quirks 0x2
[    4.158481] firewire_core 0000:08:00.0: created device fw0: GUID 00000000000002ea, S400
[  454.107114] firewire_ohci 0000:08:00.0: isochronous cycle inconsistent
[  454.612096] firewire_core 0000:08:00.0: rediscovered device fw0
[  454.631461] firewire_core 0000:08:00.0: created device fw1: GUID 0000850000a1c0c4, S100
[  454.632810] firewire_core 0000:08:00.0: phy config: new root=ffc1, gap_count=5
[  461.814961] firewire_ohci 0000:08:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x000e address=0xbfe8a000 flags=0x0050]
[  461.814973] firewire_ohci 0000:08:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x000e address=0xbfe8a040 flags=0x0050]
[  461.824940] firewire_ohci 0000:08:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x000e address=0xbfe8a000 flags=0x0050]
[  461.824948] firewire_ohci 0000:08:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x000e address=0xbfe8a040 flags=0x0050]
[  469.329638] firewire_ohci 0000:08:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x000e address=0xbabc3000 flags=0x0050]
[  469.329651] firewire_ohci 0000:08:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x000e address=0xbabc3040 flags=0x0050]
[  469.329750] firewire_ohci 0000:08:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x000e address=0xbabc3000 flags=0x0050]

... and so on.
so far i've tried every single option and output format in dvgrab, including v4l2 mode and specifying the device manually, which results in an error and then not detecting any input from the DV device:
sudo dvgrab -buffers 512 -f dv2 -noavc -nostop -showstatus -V -input /dev/fw1 test

v4l2reader.cc:70: In function "virtual bool v4l2Reader::Open()": "ioctl( VIDIOC_QUERYCAP, &cap )" evaluated to -1
v4l2reader.cc:70: errno: 25 (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
Waiting for DV...
^C""     0.00 MiB 0 frames
Capture Stopped
Error: no DV

in fact, using the -input flag to specify the input device (either fw0 or fw1, fw1 being the device with matching GUID that dvgrab managed to find before) always results in getting stuck on Waiting for DV....
one last thing to note is that while the driver can clearly see the camcorder, and dvgrab can talk to it sort of, other applications like OBS and Discord cannot see it as a camera (though i'm not terribly surprised by this either).
WinDV understandably can't see the camcorder as a device through wine, nor is it possible to run it inside VirtualBox and for WinDV to see the camcorder from there. i've had no success trying to create a bootable Windows live USB (either Windows 10 or Windows XP), and i'd rather not have to dual boot.
is there any way around this problem, which does seem to just be a straight up driver bug? is there an alternative to dvgrab for Linux? are there alternative drivers i could install/switch to? is there a different virtual machine software which can pass-through the firewire device (although if the Linux drivers are broken i'd be surprised)?

edit 1: here's the relevant part of lspci output in case that is useful:
sudo lspci -vv

08:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments TSB43AB23 IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 32 (500ns min, 1000ns max), Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 24
    IOMMU group: 13
    Region 0: Memory at fc204000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Region 1: Memory at fc200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME+
    Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
    Kernel modules: firewire_ohci

edit 2: Kino produces the exact same artefacts all over the video stream.
